# JSON.stringify doesn't work as expected on changed object. How to handle this?

Tags: javascript, json, scope, mozilla, stringify

I have removed my question text, as it didn't address the real error in my code. The two answers fully explain my error, and why I had made it.

Comment: Uh, what did you expect? That's just the result that `JSON.stringify` is supposed to give with those arguments.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with prototype inheritance as in the question that you linked.

Comment: _"Which Workaround to use?"_ Workaround for what? It's not clear what result you're expecting. Could you tell us that? (i.e. Show us the console output you think you're supposed to be seeing).

Comment: @John: But if you specify to only stringify `changedProperties` properties, you won't get `a` properties! Why are you filtering them at all?

Comment: @John: Your problems are neither related to the use of the `this` keyword nor to variable scopes, that's why I have removed those tags from the question.

Comment: @John: Please explain what you are intending to use `basicObjectElements` for and what you think passing them to `JSON.stringify` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument  to `JSON.stringify` is applied recursively, not just at the top level. You're not seeing the `"a"` property because your `basicObjectElements` array doesn't contain `"a"`. You will see it if you do this:

```
var basicObjectElements = ["changedProperties", "a"];
```

Comment: @John: So what? The replacers (including propertyname-array filters) need to be applied to every visited object, otherwise they'd be useless. If you want per-object distinctive behaviour, use `.toJSON` methods.